# Is it possible to convert a Gaussian Mixture Model implementation into a Categorical Mixture Model?

Tags: regression, matlab, mixture-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, link-function

I am modelling whether a customer will spend when given a voucher. I have a theory that a customer falls into one of two latent classes: call them spendthrift and miser. So I would like to fit a categorical mixture model, with a binary outcome (spend or not spend), with two unobserved latent categories, so that each category corresponds to different means of a Bernoulli distribution, i.e. probability spendthrift/miser will spend given a voucher.

Matlab has an implementation for a Gaussian Mixture Model. I would like to know whether I can convert this to a categorical mixture model.

I am thinking that I should be able to, as this in some way seems to be an extension of linear models to generalised linear models, in the sense that instead of minimising least squares, you use the inverse link function and maximise the log-likelihood of the predicted outcome.

Comment: What do you mean "convert"?  That the Gaussian mixture model is a special case of the mixture of logistic regressions, or vice versa?

Comment: I would say the Gaussian mixture model is a special case of the mixture of logistic regressions, in the sense that the linear model is a special case of the generalised linear model.

Comment: It's true that the **Gaussian mixture** $\subset$ **GLM mixture**,  but it sounds like you asking if **logistic mixture** $\subset$ **Gaussian mixture**, which is not true.  (Though you can show that if $Y|X \sim \mbox{Normal}(\mu_x | \sigma^2)$, where $X$ is binary, then $\mbox{logit} P(X|Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Y$ for some $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$,  ie, ordinary $X|Y$ is a one-component logistic regression.) Does Matlab implement a mixture of GLMs?  In R, these are available in flexmix.

Comment: all matlab has is Gaussian mixtures, and I was hoping to extend it to the logistic mixture. If it fails I will have to use R with mixtools or as you suggest flexmix.